# Overset and mathbb collision

Tags: math-mode, superscripts

I have ran into really funny trouble trying to use `\overset` and `\mathbb` the same time. I need to do something like this:

[image]

but with the T as mathbb, i.e. `\mathbb{\overset{m}T}_{ij}`. When I try it, this happens:

[image]

- Why?
- How can I make it work?

**Note:** Putting `\overset` before the mathbb doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put the T inside the `overset`:

`\overset{m}{\mathbb{T}}_{ij}`

[image]

Comment: Done. The answer was posted so immediately I couldn't do that cause of 10 mins non-optional delay.