# Math in the Document title

Tags: errors, amsmath, titles

I wanted to include the following into my title:
`$\mathbb{R^{2}}$` and expected the following output:

[image: Expected]

but I instead keep getting this:

[image: Actual]

If I copy the weird symbol in the superscript over R, it gives me a "2" in the notepad, but doesn't render it properly. 
How can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The exponent should be _outside_ `\mathbb`: `\mathbb{R}^2`. Similar to [this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281165/82917).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\title{$\mathbb{R}^2$}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```