# Why does \mathbf work with minuscle letters but \mathcal does not?

Tags: amsmath

If I type

```
\mathbf{e}
```

I see what I expect, but if I type

```
\mathcal{e}
```

the result is a symbol that is certainly not a calligraphic 'e'. Is this a misconfiguration on my part or is it purpose? In the latter case, what is the rationele?

Comment: There are just no lower-case calligraphic letters in the standard packages. You are doing nothing wrong.

Comment: [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281165/82917) is about `\mathbb` instead of `\mathcal` but the underlying issue is the same.

Answer (score 2):

You must load a package which defines lowercase `\mathcal` letters.  If you are allowed to use it, I recommend `unicode-math`.

If you need to use legacy fonts, there are a few that contain a lowercase `\mathcal` alphabet, such as `newpxmath`, and a few that contain lowercase `\mathscr` but not `\mathcal`, such as `stix2`.

It is also possible to load the script or calligraphic alphabets of many different packages, with scaling, through `mathalpha`, and this is the best way to load a different calligraphic math alphabet in legacy LaTeX.

With the default `\mathcal{e}`, LaTeX will look up the AsCII value of `e` in a symbol font and, since it does not contain an ℯ , give you mojibake.